# Apache server immediately shuts down

Tags: apache-http-server

I just installed MySql 5.1.49, Apache 2.2.16 and PHP 5.3.3 on my Vista Home Basic. I followed the instructions in the "Sam's Teach Yourself", adding:

```
LoadModule php5_module C:/php/php5apache2_2.dll
PHPIniDir "C:/php/"
```

and

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
```

I changed the Listening port to 8080 and the domain is localhost. When I start the server it pops open the window for less than a second and then closes.

What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked logs?

Comment: Here is what I get:
<code>

  [notice] Parent: Created child process 3956
 [notice] Child 3956: Child process is running
[Wed Aug 18 22:41:05 2010] [notice] Child 1224: Released the start mutex
[Wed Aug 18 22:41:05 2010] [notice] Child 3956: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Aug 18 22:41:05 2010] [notice] Child 3956: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Aug 18 22:41:06 2010] [notice] Child 1224: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Aug 18 22:41:06 2010] [notice] Child 3956: Starting thread to listen on port 8080.
[Wed Aug 18 22:41:07 2010] [notice] Child 1224: Child process is exiting
</code>

Comment: There isn't enough information in the log portion you provide to figure out what's wrong. Increase your LogLevel to `debug` and append the log lines to your question (so that it's more readable). Alternatively, you can debug apache from the command line: `httpd -e debug -X`. Paste the output.

Answer (score 0):

It could be running as a service or something, if you try connect to localhost:8080, do you get anything? Alternatively, is apache2.exe running?

Comment: If I use port 80 I receive the message that the port is in use and can't access it or something to that effect. 

How do I tell if .exe is running? I think it is running because I can select stop from the server command.

If I open up the standard "it Works" file, what displays is the HTML code and not the output itself. If I try to access the phpinfo file I created, on localhost/phpinfo.php, I get an error saying the server could not find it.